# Azure Search returning incorrect results

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using **Azure Search** to query a data set relating to documents. I'm querying the data to fetch the documents that are owned by a particular user based on  their email address.

The data set within the index contains a column called *UploadedBy* which represents the user who uploaded the document.

My query looks like this.

```
search=myuseremail@mycompany.com&searchFields=UploadedByEmail
```

The search query speficies the value to look for and the column in which to search for it. However, I'm getting results returned that do not match this search criteria i.e. where the email address contains a different email address.

How do I prevent these from being returned? Am I missing something from my seach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably you're getting results that match:

myuseremail@abcde.com

and

*@mycompany.com

this is not wrong, it's the expected behavior since an email has '.' and it's considered a stop word. If you want the exact match, you should use search="myuseremail@mycompany.com", escape your '.' or replace them to another char that is not a stop word.

As another option, use a custom analyzer to avoid breaking on "." for emails.

Comment: Ahh that must be it. When I search using other terms such as username that don't contain the stop characters I get the correct results returned. Thanks for the info I appreciate it :)